# wget через cron усекает массив $_REQUEST до первого значения

Tags: php, cron, wget

Хочу передать скрипту более одного параметра. Для чистоты эксперимента создал простой скрипт:

```
<?php var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Обращаюсь к нему напрямую из браузера и вижу оба параметра:

```
http://server/test.php?route=test&param=p1

array(2) { ["route"]=> string(4) "test" ["param"]=> string(2) "p1" }
```

Через ISPManager хостера создаю задание cron и вижу только первый параметр:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://server/test.php?route=test&param=p1 >/dev/null 2>&1

array(1) { ["route"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Что это может быть?

- особенности ручного исполнения заданий cron у ISPManager?
- неправильно созданный запрос cron (экранирование символов, etc?)
- настройки cron / php / nginx?

Comment: неправильно созданный запрос cron (экранирование символов, etc?) Попробуй в кавычки ссылку взять. Скорей всего дальше первого & не читается ссылка

Comment: Смотри https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474482/why-wget-ignores-query-string-in-the-url, нужно заключать адрес в двойные кавычки т.к. & - это специальный символ для консольной команды.

Comment: Двойные кавычки - первое что пробовал. Результат - вообще пустой экран.

Comment: все, понял. отключил > /dev/null и увидел )

Answer (score 2):

`&` — это разделитель команд в posix-совместимых оболочках.

чтобы строка с *url* не интерпретировалась как команда оболочки, а передавалась вызываемой программе «как есть», её надо заключить в одинарные кавычки:

```
программа опции 'http://адрес?параметр1&параметр2'
```